# sed append text after N-th occurrence

Tags: bash, sed, gnu-sed

I have a template of the following script and I need to insert the different `PARAM` value for each case.

```
case $1 in
1)
    export PARAM=
    ;;
2)
    export PARAM=
    ;;
3)
    export PARAM=
    ;;
esac
```

I just found an example how to insert the value for the 1st case `PARAM`:

```
sed -i '/export PARAM=/{s//export PARAM=1212212121/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

but how can I do this for cases 2 and 3?

Comment: You need the different values for each PATTERN or same ?

Comment: different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
n=2 v=11212212121
sed -ri '/export PARAM=/{x;s/^/x/;/x{'$n'}/!{x;b};x;s/(export PARAM=).*/\1'$v'/;:a;n;ba}' file
```

Keep a counter in the hold space and if the counter matches your expectation, substitute and then print out the remainder of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -v v="1212212121" -v n=2 '/Param/{c++} c==n-1{$(NF)+=" "v}1' file
awk -v v="1212212333" -v n=3 '/Param/{c++} c==n-1{$(NF)+=" "v}1' file
```

and so on...

Explanation:

- `/Param/{c++}` increments a counter `c` every time the pattern `/Param/` is found.
- `c==n-1` checks if `c` has the desired value and adds the value add the
- `1` is always *true*. `awk` will print all lines.
- `-v v="1212212121" -v n=2` passes the variables `v` and `n` to the script.